# How to center responsive embedded youtube iframe?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying center an embedded responsive youtube iframe in a Wordpress text box and I cant get it to center.

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe.......></iframe></div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.video-container {
position:relative;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
padding-top:30px;
height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
    .video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

I've tried `<div class="video-container" style="text-align: center;">` before the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code with this

```
.video-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `text-align: center;` and `align-items: center;` properties to `.video-container` tag in the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

if we use flex as example.

```css
.video-container {
  padding: 3rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: #f00 2px dashed;
}

.video-container iframe {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  outline: #0f0 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe>
  </iframe>
</div>
```